# T-SQL: test condition if match other table, otherwise include without test

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, conditional-statements, where-clause

Here's what I'm trying to do but I can't quite get the syntax right:

```
SELECT 
    myKey1, myDate1
FROM 
    myTable1, 
    (SELECT myKey2, myDate2 FROM myTable2) as myDatesQuery
WHERE
    -- myTable1.myKey1 = myDatesQuery.myKey2 AND myTable1. myDate1 < myDatesQuery. myDate2
    -- OR myTable1.myKey1 not found in myDatesQuery
```

So if myKey1 doesn't exist in myDatesQuery then include it. If myKey1 = myKey2 only include it if myDate1 is before myDate2.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Select myTable1.myKey1, myTable1.myDate1
    FROM 
(SELECT myKey2, myDate2 FROM myTable2) as myDatesQuery
left outer join myTable1 
        on myTable1.myKey1 = myDatesQuery.myKey2
        where myTable1.myKey1 is null or myTable1.myDate1< myDatesQuery.MyDate2
```